# Cannot get Ubuntu 13.10 to work with AMD Catalyst 13.12 - black screen

Tags: ubuntu, amd-catalyst, ubuntu-13.10

I have installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 13.10 x64 and AMD Catalyst 13.12. When booting up, I see the Ubuntu logo splash screen for a second, then it just goes to a black screen. I am using the R9 290x graphics card.

Here is my install steps:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases linux-headers-generic libqtgui4 lib32gcc1

sudo sh *.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/saucy

sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb

sudo aticonfig --initial -f --adapter=all

sudo reboot
```

Then system reboots, black screen.

Then I come upon this thread: [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716003/error-installing-amd-catalyst-13-12-driver)

I remove my current installation of catalyst, reconfigure my xorg.conf.

I do the steps in the patch thread and then reinstall the catalyst 13.12 with the patch.

I get the same result: reboot and then black screen.

So I take a peek at the Xorg.0.log file and grep and see exactly this problem: [Xorg.conf problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104434/how-to-safely-give-non-root-access-to-lib-so-that-catalyst-hardware-acceleration)

I don't have a folder called `/usr/lib64` or `/usr/X11R6...`, so I do the recommended change:

```
cd /usr ; sudo ln -svT lib /usr/lib64
```

Then I created the folder directories:

```
mkdir /usr/X11R6
mkdir /usr/X11R6/lib64
....
cp /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_dri.so /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/
```

I manually copied the fglrx_dri.so file to the X11R6 folders. This made the errors go away in the Xorg.0.conf files. I reboot, and same problem: see Ubuntu splash screen for a second, then black screen.

The system does seem to recognize the graphics card because when I do this:

```
sudo aticonfig --lsa
* 0.  01:00.0 AMD Radeon R9 290 Series

* - Default adapter
```

But when I do this:

```
sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --odgt
ERROR - X needs to be running to perform AMD Overdrive(TM) commands
```

So I try to start X:

```
sudo xinit
```

But it tells me that `(EE) Server is already active for display 0`

I tried turning off lightdm and restarting X:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo xinit
```

Then I see the Lightdm saying it's being started and a bunch of text prints out.. but it stops at:

```
....
Loading extension GLESX
Loading extension AMDXVOPL
Loading extension AMDXVBA
```

Now I don't know how else to solve this.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/411564/black-screen-after-installing-gflrx-on-ubuntu-13-10/437766#437766

This will fix you right up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

ditto, had the same problem with 12.04.4 w/ LTS enablement stack lts-raring

you can go into the terminal via Ctrl+Alt+F1, do an `lsmod | grep fglrx` to verify the module is in fact fully loaded

It should show something like:

```
fglrx                5294837  69
amd_iommu_v2           19068  1 fglrx
```

Another thing you can try, does 13.4 work?

```
wget --referer='http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86_64' http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
```